# Is it possible to create 2 where clauses with an if statement?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

We got the following Entities: GeoShape (abstract, id, latitude and longitude), GeoCircle (just a radius) and GeoPolygon (just a polygon column).

Now i want to query all shapes with something like this:

```
if polygon is not null then 
  return ST_CONTAINS(polygon, ...)
else lat,lng in circle then
  return in cirlce
```

But what i got is this:

```
if polygon is not null and ST_CONTAINS(polygon, ...) then 
  return true
else lat,lng in circle then
  return in cirlce
```

I tried to create the following querybuilder but cannot archive what i want:

```
        $queryBuilder
        ->join(sprintf('%s.geoShape', $alias), 'geoShape')
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->isNotNull('polygon'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('ST_CONTAINS(polygon, Point(:longitude, :latitude))', true)
        ))


        // thats my problem. i don't know how to do the else case


        ->orWhere('
            6371000 * acos(
                cos(
                    radians( :latitude )
                ) * cos(
                    radians( geoShape.center.latitude )
                ) * cos(
                    radians( geoShape.center.longitude ) - radians( :longitude )
                ) + sin(
                    radians( :latitude )
                ) * sin(
                    radians( geoShape.center.latitude )
                )
            ) <= :radius
        ')
        ->setParameters(
            array(
                'latitude' => $location->getLatitude(),
                'longitude' => $location->getLongitude(),
                'radius' => $radius
            )
        );

    return $queryBuilder;
```

The polygon has to be more important then the circle. If the location is not in the polygon then the query should stop and not check for the circle. Only if no polygon is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Now i just ask for the type in both cases.

```
        $qb
        ->join(sprintf('%s.geoShape', $alias), 'shape')
        ->leftJoin(GeoPolygon::class, 'p', Join::WITH, 'shape.id = p.id')
        ->leftJoin(GeoCircle::class, 'c', Join::WITH, 'shape.id = c.id')
        ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
            $qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('shape', GeoPolygon::class),
            $qb->expr()->eq('ST_CONTAINS(p.polygon, Point(:longitude, :latitude))', true)
        ))
        ->orWhere($qb->expr()->andX(
            $qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('shape', GeoCircle::class),
            $qb->expr()->lte('
            6371000 * acos(
                cos(
                    radians( :latitude )
                ) * cos(
                    radians( shape.center.latitude )
                ) * cos(
                    radians( shape.center.longitude ) - radians( :longitude )
                ) + sin(
                    radians( :latitude )
                ) * sin(
                    radians( shape.center.latitude )
                )
            )
        ', $radius)
        ))
        ->setParameters(
            array(
                'latitude' => $location->getLatitude(),
                'longitude' => $location->getLongitude()
            )
        );

    return $qb;
```